# What causes segmentation fault when returning a list from a member function?

Tags: c++, netbeans, segmentation-fault

I'm using Netbeans 7.4 with cygwin compilers on Windows 8.
I get segmentation fault and I cannot find the source of it.

**Node.h**

```
class Node {
public:

    // Getters & Setters
    inline std::list<Node*> getAdjL() const { return adjacentList; }

    // Member Functions
    void printAdj() const;

private:
    unsigned id;
    std::list<Node*> adjacentList;
}
```

I also have the print function as a member function (which works fine when called form outside):

**Node.cpp**

```
void Node::printAdj() const {
    std::cout << "Adjacent list of node with id: " << id << std::endl;
    for(std::list<Node*>::const_iterator it = adjacentList.begin();
            it != adjacentList.end(); ++it){
        std::cout << (*it)->getId() << "\t";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
Node* u = NULL;
while( some condition ){
    u = smallest(nodes);    // smallest distance & un-visited node

    list<Node*>::const_iterator iter = u->getAdjL().begin();
    cout << endl << "size: " << u->getAdjL().size() << endl;
    cout << "printing info" << endl;
    u->printAdj();                     // works just fine (member function)
    cout << (*iter)->getId() << endl;  // segmentation fault
```

**Output**

```
size: 1
printing info
Adjacent list of node with id: 0
9


RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 2s)
```

When I tried to debug, I was prompted that I got SIGSEGV (segmentation fault). What causes this?

Note: I believe I only included relevant part but comment if you need extra code.

Comment: `getId()` Are you sure this is safely functioning ??

Comment: `inline unsigned getId() const { return id; }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This method

```
inline std::list<Node*> getAdjL() const { return adjacentList; }
```

returns a copy of `adjacentList` as a temporory object, which gets destroyed immediatelly after this line:

```
list<Node*>::const_iterator iter = u->getAdjL().begin();
```

so your `iter` is an iterator from a destroyed object and points to garbage

You might want to make your getter return the *reference* to the value

```
inline const std::list<Node*>& getAdjL() const
```

This should make things work. Or store the value returned by the `getAdjL()` somewhere

Comment: I knew it... However I tried to fix it by returning a pointer but I couldn't make it work. I'll check it out once I get to code again.

Comment: changing it into `inline const std::list<Node*>& getAdjL() const { return adjacentList; }` caused segmentation fault at `list<Node*>::const_iterator iter = u->getAdjL().begin();`. 

Is assigning the returned list to somewhere the only way?

Comment: actually, assigning it to another list defined in main.cpp doesn't do the trick either. I guess something else must be wrong :/

Comment: I guess than after the answer's fix, you get null pointer from `u = smallest(nodes);`

Comment: nope, `u` is not null. I tested it by accessing its elements. Even `u->printAdj()` works on this case which proves its not null. The member function works when I execute it before the iterator initialization.

Comment: Turns out the error was due to a corrupted project file (object files somehow stay out of date. I had to delete them and re-build the project). Thanks for pointing out the garbage copy tho.